# Running ,jmx file on a aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am new to jmeter. I have written a .jmx script  containing few http samplers for performance testing and can locally run it and see the results in the summary report.

Question is how can I achieve the same on a AWS ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your script on EC2 instance absolutely the same manner as in local environment. However if you're talking about completely new instance without anything installed consider the following checklist:

1. Java 6 SDK by Oracle, 64-bit installed, `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set, /bin folder of Java SDK installation is in `PATH` variable.
2. JMeter downloaded and unpacked. Relevant `HEAP` and other JVM_ARGS overrides are made in JMeter startup scripts.
3. Any CSV data files, configuration files, plugins, extensions are transferred to relevant locations so JMeter could find and use them
4. Perform sample run with 1 user and 1 iteration to see whether everything is good. Inspect `jmeter.log` file for any warnings and errors.
5. Set number of virtual users and iterations according to your load scenario.
6. Make sure that performance checklist from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) is passing for your environment
7. Run, collect metrics, analyze results, raise issues, etc.